# Spring Boot 2 and Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

I have upgraded my spring boot application to Spring boot 2. I missed that sprint boot 2 only supports tomcat 7. I deployed my application as a WAR-File to a stand alone Tomcat 7.0.62 and it's working fine. It is a REST-API-Application and all my integration tests are working well.

Where should I check for error messages. Shouldn't there be an error when starting up the application?

Comment: If everything is working fine, why do you expect en error? I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I guess you are wrong. Java 8 and Tomcat 8.5: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the file `catalina.out`. Quoting the documentation:

> When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually
>   redirected to the file named catalina.out. The name is configurable
>   using an environment variable. (See the startup scripts). Whatever is
>   written to System.err/out will be caught into that file.

The complete reference can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can find the start up logs file in {tomcat7.X}/catalina.out

while the application logs {tomcat7.X}/logs

Answer (score 0):

Although your question seems to be about finding logs for the application, your initial statement is incorrect. Spring Boot 2 does not support Java 7.

According to the Spring Documentation -

> Spring Boot 2.0 requires Java 8 or later. Java 6 and 7 are no longer
>   supported. It also requires Spring Framework 5.0